# check if any value of a column in csv file exists in a column in a second csv file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to compare columns in two csv files. Basically check if any value in one column exists in another column. If they do exist print out any such values.

Ex:
file1:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 789 |
| efg | 766 |
| hij | 456 |

file2:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| klm | 789 |
| nop | 766 |
| abc | 456 |

I need to compare if any values in file2 'id' column exist in file1 'id' column. In the example above 'abc' is one value that is repeated and needs to be print out.

Is there a bash script that can do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1 { next } NR==FNR { map[$1]=$2;next } map[$1]!="" { print;print $1"\t"map[$1] } ' file1 file2
```

If  the line number is 1 (FNR==1), skip to the next line. When processing the first file (NR=FNR), create an array map with the first space separated field as the index and the second field the value. Then, when processing the second file, if there is an entry for the first field in map, print the line along with the entry in the map array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python, you can use `pandas` library.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(yourdata, columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']) 
duplicate = df[df.duplicated()]

print(duplicate)
```

For more detailed info, you can check this [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicate-rows-in-a-dataframe-based-on-all-or-selected-columns/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` (and `tail` and `sort` and Bash's process substitution):

```
$ join -j 1 -o "1.1" <(tail -n +2 file1 | sort) <(tail -n +2 file2 | sort)
abc
```

Explained:

- `join -j 1 -o "1.1"` join on the first space-separated field, output the first field of the first file
- `<(...)` Bash's process substitution
- `tail -n +2 file1` ditch the header
- `| sort` `join` expects the files to be sorted

(Yeah, I'd use @RamanSailopal's awk solution, too, ++)